# Azure Active Directory Resulting in CORS Error on SignOut

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP MVC Web App that is using Azure AD as a form of login and logout for the users. The App has been registered with Azure AD and the login works flawlessly.

It is important to note that I make use of the OWIN interface for both the Login and Log Out.

The issue is that when I press the logout button on the app the following code executes:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, 
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

Here the user is logged out successfully but the web page does not redirect to the login page. Instead it results in a CORS error between two Microsoft sites while re-direction from https://login.windows.net/.../oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=... to https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=...

The CORS error is: Redirect from {url 1} to {url 2} has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1089' is therefore not allowed access.

I am a little at a loss whether this is an issue in my app or azure setting as I cannot control this redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) is a code sample works well to integrate with Azure AD. To troubleshoot the issue, you may share the code you were developing.

Please remove the sensitive information before sharing, you can public the code sample on GitHub.

### Update

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that is the code sample that I followed in order to get the connection with Azure AD working. My implementation is exactly the same, the only difference are the specific values such as the App ID and Tenant. The values for the AAD Instance is "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" while the redirect logout URL is "http://localhost:1089/"

Comment: The code sample works well for me. Did you add any custom code? Based on my understanding, the redirection between two sites above you mentioned is caused by set the **Location** property by the web browser(See the figure in  the update post). It shouldn't get the CORS issue which is caused by JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have managed to solve it, the issue was due to the UI framework that I am using as it was not posting back to the controller but using Javascript to execute client side. Resulting in the CORS error.

Comment: @JeanClaudeAbela, please elaborate a bit on "posting back to the controller"? We have the same issue and we don't understand what's happening.

Comment: @MiroJ.did you find a solution. I have the same problem with an msal-angular demo application accessing my web API